# Laravel: Save Method not working

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to save/update data with this method `save`, but it doesnt work, it says that a parameter doesn't have a default value, but I'm sending it as a part of what I want to insert/update. Here is my code

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $producto_nombre = Producto_nombre::where('codigo', $request->codigo)->first();
        $reglas = [];
        //Comprobar unique en update
        if (isset($producto_nombre)) {
            $reglas = [
                'codigo' => [
                    'required',
                    Rule::unique('producto_nombre')->ignore($producto_nombre->id),
                ],
                'descripcion' => 'required'];
        } else {
            $reglas = ['descripcion' => 'required', 'codigo' => 'required|unique:producto_nombre'];
        }
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $reglas);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(array('errors' => $validator->getMessageBag()->toArray()));
        } else {
            $collection = $request->all();
            $this->agregarProducto($collection);

        }
    }


    public function agregarProducto($collection)
    {
        $producto_nombre = Producto_nombre::where('codigo', 
                           $collection['codigo'])->first();
        $empresa = Empresa::where('id', $collection['empresa_id'])->first();
        //Si esta vacio crea una nuevo
        if (empty($producto_nombre)) {
            $producto_nombre = new Producto_nombre();
        }

        $collection['iva_id'] = Iva::where('actual', 1)->first()->id;
//        dd($collection);
//        $producto_nombre->iva_id = Iva::where('actual', 1)->first()->id;
        $producto_nombre->save($collection);
        $producto = $empresa->productos()->where('producto_nombre_id',                 
                     $producto_nombre->id)->first();
        // Si esta vacio crea nuevo producto
        if (empty($producto)) {
            $producto = new Producto();
            $this->crearProductoSucursales($producto_nombre->id, 
                                           $collection['empresa_id']);
        }
        $producto->producto_nombre_id = $producto_nombre->id;
//            TODO editar en transferencias y compras en 0 maximo y minimo
        $producto->stock_maximo = $collection['stock_maximo'];
        $producto->stock_minimo = $collection['stock_minimo'];
        $producto->descuento = $collection['descuento'];
        $producto->save();
        $empresa->productos()->syncWithoutDetaching($producto->id);
    }
```

This is what $collection has

```
array:13 [
  "codigo" => "prueba"
  "descripcion" => "prueba"
  "con_iva" => "1"
  "desglose" => "0"
  "costo_actual" => "12"
  "precio" => "19.64"
  "descuento" => "12"
  "costo_promedio" => "0"
  "maximo" => "45"
  "minimo" => "2"
  "linea" => "2"
  "seccion" => "2"
  "empresa_id" => "2"
]
```

I've created the method `agregarProducto` because I want to reuse it in other controllers

### Update

Error Says:

> "message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'codigo' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into producto_nombre`(updated_at, created_at) values (2018-04-05 10:09:28, 2018-04-05 10:09:28))",`

Comment: Upload what the error says

Comment: Sure `"message": "SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'codigo' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `producto_nombre` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2018-04-05 10:09:28, 2018-04-05 10:09:28))",`

Comment: Seems like `codigo` is set as `not null` and you are not assigning anything to it.

Comment: Did you set `Producto_nombre::$fillable`?

Comment: Yep it isnt nullable, but I'm sending it in my array, is it wrong?, I was doing something like this before `$producto_nombre->codigo = $collection['codigo'];` and it was working, but now I want to update the fields if the product already exist

Comment: @Jonas Staudenmeir, yes :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to class `Producto_nombre` and add:

```
class Producto_nombre
{
...
    protected $fillable = ['codigo'];
...
```

Then replace

```
$producto_nombre->save($collection);
```

with

```
$producto_nombre->fill($collection);
$producto_nombre->save();
```

The parameters for method `save()` will work for things like disable timestamp and other options. In your case, you are trying to fill the object with data from array, so you must use `fill($collection)` or, if it's a new register, you could use `create($collection)`

Comment: I've already done that, that's why I dont understand what laravel wants haha

Comment: As https://stackoverflow.com/users/1580044/felippe-duarte pointed you need to use the fillable property in the model in order to make this assigment works `$producto_nombre->fill($collection);`. If you want to save the descripcion field also then include it too. More info at https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Thank you so much it worked, I'm using the save method to create a new register as well and to update if one exists